# Преобразование формулы в C

Tags: c

Получаю неизвестную ошибку в виде нулей в ответе. В чем может быть моя ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int  main()
{
    int a = 3,b = 2;
    float x,y,c = 2.1,d=2.5;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    scanf("%f",&y);
    float ThirdStep = 1/a * tan(a*x/2) ;
    float FourthStep = 1/2* log(a*x-1/2);
    float t2 = ThirdStep + FourthStep;
    printf("%f\n",t2);

}
```

```
Output:0.00000
```

[image: Формула]

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная ошибка...

```
1/2
```

это — *целочисленное* деление, с отбрасыванием дробной части, и это не 0.5, а просто 0...

Как и в

```
1/a
```

Пишите `0.5` и `1./a`